# scale Cassandra cluster and redistribute data

Tags: cassandra

I have a single node, single replica cluster. I'm looking to scale it up to have 4 nodes, with a replica factor of 2. The `ALTER KEYSPACE` command works the the replication, but how to I distribute the existing data across nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you’re using Vnodes, you don’t need to worry about that.  Simply add your new nodes, and the token range recalculations happen automatically.  Once you’ve added all new nodes, run a `nodetool cleanup` on every node and you should be all set.

Comment: yes, thanks. Using `nodetool ring` and some of the other tips from these answers helped to understand where the data is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166650/view-cassandra-partitions-using-cqlsh